# my GUI application does`nt work correctly. does not make a random number

Tags: java, user-interface

I was writing a program in java but when I want to compile it I had a problem.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class y implements ActionListener {
    JFrame f;
    JButton b;
    JTextField jtf1;
    JTextField jtf2;
    JTextField jtf3;

    y() {

        f = new JFrame("Random Number");
        f.setBounds(0, 0, 1370, 740);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setLayout(null);
        b = new JButton("submit");
        b.setBounds(200, 450, 250, 70);
        f.add(b);
        jtf1 = new JTextField();
        jtf1.setBounds(200, 300, 250, 70);
        f.add(jtf1);
        jtf2 = new JTextField();
        jtf2.setBounds(200, 150, 250, 70);
        f.add(jtf2);
        jtf3 = new JTextField();
        jtf3.setBounds(700, 300, 500, 70);
        jtf3.setEditable(false);
        f.add(jtf3);
        Font f1 = new Font("Segoe Script", Font.BOLD, 30);
        jtf1.setFont(f1);
        jtf2.setFont(f1);
        jtf3.setFont(f1);
        b.setFont(f1);
        b.addActionListener(this);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String s1 = jtf1.getText();
        String s2 = jtf2.getText();
        int a = Integer.parseInt(s1);
        int b = Integer.parseInt(s2);

        if (a < 0) {
            jtf3.setText("the numbers must be bigger than 0");
        }
        if (b < 0) {
            jtf3.setText("the numbers must be bigger than 0");
        }
        if (b < a) {
            jtf3.setText("the second number must be bigger then the first");
        } else {

            Random randomObj = new Random();
            int randomNum = randomObj.nextInt((b - a)) + a;

            jtf3.setText("the random number is : " + " " + randomNum);

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new y();
    }
}
```

but when i compile it , it does not work correctly . It does not make a random number and it does not load errors.
what can I do ?
It does not show errors. The code can not setText JTextFied.
I had tried a lot of ways than we can make a random number. Some of them does not work and some of them does not work correctly.
my compiler is : `InteliJ IDEA`

Comment: “It does not show errors.”  Yes it does.  An exception is occurring in your `actionPerformed` method.  Add some System.out.println statements to determine why the exception is happening.  (Hint:  `System.out.println(s1); System.out.println(s2);`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you had a simple typo mistake:

```
    String s1 = jtf1.getText();
    String s2 = jtf1.getText();
```

change it to

```
    String s1 = jtf2.getText();
    String s2 = jtf1.getText();
```

and it will work!

I also suggest to place jtf2 above jtf1 as jtf1 refers to first number and jtf2 refers to second one.